# Sagepay error 5068: encryption method not supported (Upgrade from 2.22 to 3.00) Classic ASP

Tags: encryption, vbscript, asp-classic, opayo

I've already looked through answers to other questions on the Sagepay protocol upgrade from 2.22 to 3.00.

I think I am trying to update the encryption method from Xor to AES so the 3.00 protocol will work but have got stuck on the Sagepay error 5068: the encryption method is not supported by this protocol.

I have tried a couple of things suggested from other peoples questions that have been asked but have not archived much from this.

Here is an extract of the Sage pay file, showing how the `crypt` variable is built:

```vb
<%
crypt = "VendorTxCode=" & strvendortxcode & "&"
'crypt = crypt & "Amount=1.00&" '& formatnumber(running_total,2) & "&"
crypt = crypt & "Amount=" & formatnumber(running_total,2) & "&"
crypt = crypt & "Currency=GBP&"
crypt = crypt & "Description=Order From Pyrotex Fireworx&"
crypt = crypt & "SuccessURL=http://" & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") & "/buyfireworks/success.asp&"
crypt = crypt & "FailureURL=http://" & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") & "/buyfireworks/failure.asp&"
crypt = crypt & "CustomerName=" & rs_customer.fields("inv_first_name") & " " & rs_customer.fields("inv_last_name") & "&"
crypt = crypt & "CustomerEMail=" & rs_customer.fields("email") & "&"
crypt = crypt & "VendorEMail=matt.hill@at-u.com&"
crypt = crypt & "BillingSurname=" & rs_customer.fields("inv_last_name") & "&"
crypt = crypt & "BillingFirstnames=" & rs_customer.fields("inv_first_name") & "&"
crypt = crypt & "BillingAddress1=" & rs_customer.fields("inv_address_001") & "&"
crypt = crypt & "BillingAddress2=" & rs_customer.fields("inv_address_002") & "&"        
crypt = crypt & "BillingCity=" & rs_customer.fields("inv_town") & "&"
crypt = crypt & "BillingPostCode=" & rs_customer.fields("inv_postcode") & "&"
crypt = crypt & "BillingCountry=" & "GB" & "&"
crypt = crypt & "BillingPhone=" & rs_customer.fields("inv_telephone") & "&"
crypt = crypt & "DeliverySurname=" & rs_customer.fields("del_last_name") & "&"
crypt = crypt & "DeliveryFirstnames=" & rs_customer.fields("del_first_name") & "&"      
crypt = crypt & "DeliveryAddress1=" & rs_customer.fields("del_address_001") & "&"
crypt = crypt & "DeliveryAddress2=" & rs_customer.fields("del_address_002") & "&"
crypt = crypt & "DeliveryCity=" & rs_customer.fields("del_town") & "&"
crypt = crypt & "DeliveryPostCode=" & rs_customer.fields("del_postcode") & "&"
crypt = crypt & "DeliveryCountry=" & "GB" & "&"
crypt = crypt & "Basket=" & order_description
%>
```

This is the form further down the file, where the `Crypt` value is set:

```html
<form action="<%= gatewayUrl %>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="VPSProtocol" value="3.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="TxType" value="PAYMENT">
    <input type="hidden" name="Vendor" value="companyname">
    <input type="hidden" name="Crypt" value="<%= base64encode(simpleXor(crypt, cryptoPassword)) %>">
    <input type="submit" onclick="SagePayForm.submit();" value="Continue"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encrypting Crypt field using Classic ASP for SagePay Form Integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025330/encrypting-crypt-field-using-classic-asp-for-sagepay-form-integration)

Comment: There are plenty of existing questions on this topic, not sure this is any different. Read through them all and try some of the suggestions. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25026284/692942, http://stackoverflow.com/q/26993768/692942, http://stackoverflow.com/q/28383077/692942. Good luck.

Comment: Also posting all that code is pointless when you miss out the most important parts, for example you could have just posted this line `<input type="hidden" name="Crypt" value="<%= base64encode(simpleXor(crypt, cryptoPassword)) %>">` but also included the definitions for `base64encode()` and `simpleXor()` that is where the problem will lie. Maybe even the first part of the code where you build up the `crypt` variable.

Comment: You say you are upgrading from `Xor` to `AES` but it looks as though the code is still using `Xor`? You'll need to use something like `rijndael.asp` script that I mention in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25026284/692942) to encrypt using AES. Not surprised SagePay is telling you the `encryption method is not supported by this protocol` if you are using `Xor`.

Comment: Although this is [tag:php] you might still find it relevant to your issue - [Sagepay error 5068: encryption method not supported (Upgrade from 2.22 to 3.00)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31111405/sagepay-error-5068-encryption-method-not-supported-upgrade-from-2-22-to-3-00?rq=1), answers point to removing the [tag:base64] encoding.

Comment: Thanks guys for the suggestions but none of the ways that have been suggested before seem to help me. Just wondering is there anyone that would be able to help me out?

Comment: What do you want us to do? I've asked questions about the code you haven't bothered to answer, I'm not sure how we are suppose to help you if you won't help yourself?

Comment: Okay, well as I did not write the code I can not tell you everything. I believe that the code is still running, yeas i need to convert from XOR to AES.